# After filling textbox with calender control , textchanged event is not firing .. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I am filling the textbox with calender control, that textbox after filling with date . Thereafter the textbox contain a textchanged event which is calculating the number of days from today date to the date dselected . 
 All Code is inside update panel..
  The event of textbox is not fireing....

Comment: Please provide your code mate

Comment: Look what DGibbs writes. You can raise the event yourself programmatically: textBox_TextChanged(this, new EventArgs());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the MSDN article for the [TextBox.TextChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

In particular:

> The TextChanged event is raised when the content of the text box changes between posts to the server. The event is only raised if the text is changed by the user; **the event is not raised if the text is changed programmatically.**

You're changing the text programmatically. The event wont be raised.

Comment: thax for the article